# android - passing array between fragments is not working

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

On my fragment named `locate_map` I declared a string array and converted it as a String ArrayList. I would like that ArrayList be pass on my another fragment named `locate_updatedstatus`. I have a button on my `locate_map` fragment that has id `to_update_status` that would switch from `locate_map` to `locate_updatedstatus`at the same time would pass my ArrayList and display it as a listview on my `locate_updatedstatus`

There is no error upon bulding. However whenever I navigate to my `locate_updatedstatus` the app crashes.

Main activity. This is how I switch between fragments. I am using navigation drawer activity with container fragment

```
public void onSelectFragment(View v){ 
      Fragment newFragment;

       if(v == findViewById(R.id.to_update_status)){ 
            newFragment = new locate_updatedstatus();
        }
        else{
            newFragment = new locate_login();
        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

locate_map fragment

```
public class locate_map extends Fragment implements Serializable{

    public locate_map () {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locate_map, container, false);

        String[] updatedArr = {"display this", "also this"};
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(updatedArr));
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("key", (Serializable) stringList);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

locate_map xml button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/to_update_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/check_images"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Update Status"
        android:width="340dp"
        android:height="70dp"
        android:onClick="onSelectFragment"
        />
```

locate_updatedstatus fragment

```
public class locate_updatedstatus extends Fragment implements Serializable {


    public locate_updatedstatus() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locate_updatedstatus, container, false);

        ArrayList<String> stringList = (ArrayList<String>)getArguments().getSerializable("key");


                ListView listSource = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.updates);

                ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        stringList
                );

                listSource.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        return rootView; // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    }

}
```

locate_updatedstatus xml listview

```
<ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/updates"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
             />
```

I would appreciate if the answers are in detail. I am beginner on android programming please bear with me.

logcat error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference                                                                          at com.example.makati.sidebar.locate_updatedstatus.onCreateView(locate_updatedstatus.java:31)
```

Comment: what is the error in logcat?

Comment: i updated the question now with the erorr in logcat

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `bundle.putStringArray`

```
String[] updatedArr = {"display this", "also this"};
bundle.putStringArray(KEY, updatedArr)
```

and 
    `bundle.getStringArray(KEY)`

In your's code you are not adding `Bundle` as argument to `Fragment`
Please use [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to fix class constructor

Answer (score 0):

below lines code just creating the bundle and adding arraylist to it. But there is nothing specified where it will be get used.

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(updatedArr));
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("key", (Serializable) stringList);
```

Solution : hoping the first locate_login and then locate_updatedstatus fragments will be created in sequence.

locate_login fragment : trying to put content activity intent

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(updatedArr));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("key", (Serializable) stringList);
getActivity().getIntent().putExtras("key",bundle);
```

locate_upadtestatus fragment : get data from the activity intent

```
    ArrayList<String> stringList = (ArrayList<String>)getActivity().getIntent().getExtras("key");
```